# Iterrow() only assigning last value to column. How to assign iteratively

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
name:   ...  line: 
bobo    ...   10
amy     ...   5
amanda  ...   15
```

I am using the below code:

```
def test_function(df_test, column_name):
    
    for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
       
            input = row[column_name]
            df_test['col1'] = input * 1
            df_test['col2'] = input * 5
            df_test['col3'] = input * 10
    
    return df_test
```

I want each result column for col1, col2, col3 to have values based on their row['column_name'], but they are all being assigned the last value, instead of being assigned iteratively.

I am calling the function:

```
test_function(df_test, 'line')
```

What is currently being returned:

```
name:   ...  line: col1: col2: col3:
bobo    ...   10    15    75    150 
amy     ...   5     15    75    150
amanda  ...   15    15    75    150
```

What I want returned:

```
name:   ...  line: col1: col2: col3:
bobo    ...   10    10    50    100 
amy     ...   5     5    25    50
amanda  ...   15    15    75    150
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your function does nothing with `df_test` but returns it

Comment: You need to index by row as well. Otherwise you're just assigning a single value to the whole column every iteration.

Comment: Also, where and how are you calling your function? (we don't know what `column_name` you're passing)

Comment: Should the output for the first row not be 10, 50, 100?

Comment: Made the relevant edits, thanks!

Comment: "Assigning a single value to the whole column every iteration." is the problem I am struggling with.

Comment: You *really* don't need iterrows for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-assigning the whole column at every iteration of your `for` loop. You need to specify both index and column while assigning.
Try this:

```
def test_function(df_test, column_name):
    for i in df.index:
        df_test.at[i, "col1"] = df_test.at[i, column_name]
        df_test.at[i, "col2"] = df_test.at[i, column_name]*5
        df_test.at[i, "col3"] = df_test.at[i, column_name]*10
    return df_test

>>> test_function(df, "line")
    name  line  col1  col2   col3
0    bobo    10  10.0  50.0  100.0
1     amy     5   5.0  25.0   50.0
2  amanda    15  15.0  75.0  150.0
```

Alternatively, for your particular case, you don't even need to iterate over each row. You can multiply entire columns at once, like so:

```
def test_function(df_test, column_name):
    df_test["col1"] = df_test[column_name]*1
    df_test["col2"] = df_test[column_name]*5
    df_test["col3"] = df_test[column_name]*10
    return df_test

>>> test_function(df, "line")
     name  line  col1  col2  col3
0    bobo    10    10    50   100
1     amy     5     5    25    50
2  amanda    15    15    75   150
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach if you want to just do it inline:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['bobo','amy','amanda'],
    'line':[10,5,15]})

df[['col1','col2','col3']] = df['line'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x*n for n in [1,5,10]]))
```